# Using self-signed certificate while installing the Azure DevOps is causing ‘Connection isn't secure’ warning

Tags: https, azure-devops

While installing the Azure DevOps server the `<generate new self-signed certificate>` option was used in the ***Web Site Settings***:

[image]

**After the installation was successfully completed browsing to the site seems fine on the server:**

[image]

**But opening the DevOps site from another computers in the intranet shows the following warning:**

> "Your Connection for this site is not valid"

[image]

I checked that the configuration is correct according to the Microsoft documentation: [Configuring HTTPS for Azure DevOps Server](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/setup-secure-sockets-layer?view=azure-devops-2022#configuring-https-for-azure-devops-server).

**How can I solve this problem to get rid of this warning?**

Thanks

Comment: Did you install the certificate on both machines?

Comment: @Ramhound: After installing the certificate on the client machine the warning is disappeared.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From
[Web site settings and security for Azure DevOps on-premises](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/server/admin/websitesettings?view=azure-devops-2022&source=recommendations#self-signed-certificates) :

> **Self-signed certificates**
>
> Self-signed certificates are useful for trial deployments of Azure
> DevOps Server, since they are very easy to provision and use. They are
> less appropriate for production deployments of Azure DevOps Server,
> and we do not recommend they be used for Azure DevOps Server
> deployments exposed to the public internet. Generally, self-signed
> certificates are susceptible to man-in-the-middle attacks. They also
> cause problems for users, since they will cause certificate warnings
> and errors until their root certificates are installed on each client
> machine.

In other words, every certificate is issued by a Certificate Authority.
In order for it to be valid, the issuing Certificate Authority must
itself be recognized as trustworthy.

A self-signed certificate is signed by the issuing computer, so is valid
within that computer. Other computers will not recognize the issuing
computer as a known authority, so may refuse to accept that certificate.

That is why a self-signed certificate is good for testing,
where all the computers are controlled, but not good for the
wider public.

For your problem, you need to set the other computer to accept
your certificate. Depending on your browser, it may allow such
action. Otherwise, you will need to import the certificate
manually into the Certificate Store on that computer.

Comment: If I understand correct, it's no problem to use these certificates on the intranet. Only necessary to export file(s) on the server by using using the Certificates MMC snap-in and then import it on each client, to be stored under _Trusted Root Certification Authorities_. But if customers will start the service over the Internet it's necessary to issue certificates from Trusted Certificate Authorities and use Group Policy to automate distribution to clients. Is it correct?

Comment: @Jackdaw - You can always buy a certificate from a CA and skip the step of having to trust the certificate you created

Comment: @Jackdaw: You're right in principle. You can't demand from people not belonging to your organization to import or trust your certificates. You need to use certificates issued by a well-known Authority which is very likely already present in everyone's Trusted Certificate Authorities store.